# How to Hide Left Nav Menu beyond homepage in Volusion

Tags: navigation, volusion

Can someone help me figure how to hide the left nav menu via css after homepage in Volusion? I have a webstore with volusion and would like to not see the left nav after first level. Thanks!

Comment: what you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use jquery to modify css according to certain page you want to hide the nav.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var url_whatever = "http://www.yourwebsite.com/blablablayourlink.asp";

$(function(){
  if (location.href==url_whatever){
    $("#your_left_navigation_id_name").remove();
  }
})
});
```

put that code on your js file in volusion, good luck